# ¿Cuál es la métrica poética de las líneas siguientes?

Tags: poesía

En la estrofa siguiente

> De amante, carezco una onda y soñé con Inlé
>
> atraído al fondo por númenes azul oscuro
>
> y mis pies se convierten en la cola de un pez, os lo juro
>
> todo eso con mis otros sueños dorados soñé

¿se pronuncian todas las vocales en la tercera línea, o es posible que el autor use elisión?

¿Cuál será la definición del ritmo poético en cado caso, es decir, con la elisión y sin ella?

Comment: ¿Quieres decir la métrica? El ritmo (si usa yambos o troqueos, etcétera) tradicionalmente no se considera en la métrica española, que normalmente se mide en sílabas y no en pies.

Comment: Exactamente. Gracias.

Answer (score 5):

En determinar la métrica, primero recomiendo separar por sílabas, sin tener en cuenta transformaciones como sinalefa, diéresis, o sinérisis.<sup>1</sup> Así tenemos lo siguiente, contando tradicionalmente:<sup>2</sup>

```
1  2   3    4  5   6    7   8    9   10  11 12 13  14  15  16 17 18
De a-  man- te ca- rez- co  u-   na  on- da y  so- ñé  con In-lé +1  
a- tra-í-   do al  fon- do  por  núm-en- es az-ul  os- cu- ro   
y  mis pies se con-vier-ten en   la  co- la de un  pez os  lo ju-ro  
to-do  e-   so con mis  o-  tros sue-ños do-ra-dos so- ñé  +1
```

Como vemos, no hay correspondencia, así que debe haber transformaciones.  Las transformaciones posibles las marco en negrita si acaban restando una sílaba en la cuenta y en cursiva en caso de agregar una (no hay cesura, así que pueden ocurrir dondequiera).

> **De‿a** - man - te - ca - rez - **co‿u** - **na‿on** - **da‿y** - so - ñé - con - In - lé **[ <sup>+0</sup>/<sub>-4</sub> ]**
>   a - **tra‿í** - **do‿al** - fon - do - por - núm - en - es - az - ul - os - cu - ro **[ <sup>+0</sup>/<sub>-2</sub> ]**
>   y - mis - *<sup>pi</sup>∕<sub>es</sub>* - se - con - *<sup>vi</sup>∕<sub>er</sub>* - ten - en - la - co - la - **de‿un** - pez - os - lo - ju - ro **[ <sup>+2</sup>/<sub>-1</sub> ]**
>   to - **do‿e** - so - con - mis - o - tros - *<sup>su</sup>∕<sub>e</sub>* - ños - do - ra - dos - so - ñé **[ <sup>+1</sup>/<sub>-1</sub> ]**

Así para el recuento final podemos ver que el primero verso se puede pensar como de entre 14 y 18 sílabas, la segunda de entre 14 y 16, la tercera entre 17 y 20, y la cuarta de entre 15 y 17; todo depende de por cuáles transformaciones optamos.

Ello me dice que la métrica debe ser de 15 o 16 sílabas (las sinalefas y sinérisis son más comunes que las diéresis), aunque también sería bien posible algún tipo de alternación entre versos de 18 (o versos octodecasílabos) versos más cortos, sea de 16 (versos hexadecasílabos) o de 15 (versos pentadecasílabo) sílabas.  Con solo cuatro versos, es difícil saber con certeza.  Pero dejémoslo para mirar las tres posibilidades (15, 16 y 18 sílabas) con el tercer verso.

Todas las vocales probablemente se pronunciarán.  Solo hay dos que podrían elidirse, la secuencia *en la* puede poética o dialectalmente realizarse como *na*, y *de un* como *dun*, pero estas cosas normalmente escriben los poetas directamente porque son algo forzados Mucho más común sería una reducción por sinalefa que es muy natural y suave, por ejemplo, pero solo modifica, y no quita, una vocal).

Si determinamos que el patrón silábico es una alternancia de 18 con 15 o 16 sílabas, ya está, no hay modificación alguna, ya estamos a 18 sílabas.  Caso queramos 15 o 16, hay más trabajo.

Podemos primero bajarnos a 17 sílabas sinalefando el *de* y *un* (modificación muy frecuente):

> y mis pies se convierten en la cola **de‿un** pez, os lo juro

Ya dicho, es posible fusionar *en la* para tener *na* pero a menos que sea un poema muy, muy antiguo, es casi mejor no considerarlo sin que sea la única posibilidad.  Otra posibilidad sería hacer una sinafía,<sup>3.</sup> que podría bajarnos una sílaba más:

> atraí**do‿al** fondo por númenes azul oscur**o<sub>(‿y…)</sub>**
>   …mis pies se convierten en la cola **de‿un** pez, os lo juro

Ahora lo hemos bajado a 16. Pero si queremos llegar a 15, es algo más difícil.  De verdad creo que son cosas que el poeta nos debió haber indicado en tal caso.  Si no fusionamos *en la*, la otra opción (y la última que me queda), sería trasladar por completo las palabras *y mis* (ambas átonas) al segundo verso, así tendríamos:

> atraí**do‿al** fondo por númenes azul oscur**o<sub>(‿y mis…)</sub>**
>   … pies se convierten en la cola **de‿un** pez, os lo juro

En este caso, aunque habríamos subido el número de sílabas por uno, esta no se computa en el recuento por ser átona al final de la línea (solo se cuenta la primera átona después de la última tónica).  Pero repito mi aviso, esta lectura es muy forzada.

---

<sup>1. Una **sinalefa** es cuando una palabra termina en vocal y la que le sigue comienza en vocal y en vez de pronunciarse estas dos vocales en sílabas distintas, salen en una: si son diferentes, puede ser diptongo como en *libro azul* (*li-brua-zul*) o triptongo como en *ambigua idea* (*am-bi-guai-de-a*); si son iguales, solo se pronuncia una como en *entre estos* (*en-tres-tos*).  Una **sinéresis** es parecida, pero cuando dos vocales que deben pronunciarse en sílabas distintas *dentro* de una palabra se acaban pronunciando como diptongo: por ejemplo *toalla* que debe dividirse *to-a-lla* muchas veces sale como *tua-lla*.  Una **diéresis** es cuando se rompe un diptongo, pronunciándola en dos sílabas distintas (y normalmente se marca con ¨ sobre la vocal que iba a ser semivocal), como en *rüido* (*ru-i-do*) o *süave* (*su-a-ve*).</sup>

<sup>2. Tradicionalmente, cuando se cuentan las sílabas en la poesía española, se el verso acaba en palabra **aguda** (cuya última sílaba lleva el acento, como en *comí*, *cenar*), vale por una sílabas más.  Si acaba en palabra *llana* (cuya penúltima sílaba lleva el acento como en *diamante* o *estándar*), vale por cuántas tiene de verdad.  Si acaba en palabra **esdrújula** (cuya antepenúltima sílaba lleva el acento como, pues, *esdrújula* o *antepenúltima*), vale por una sílaba menos (y la rima asonante va por la última y antepenúltima sílaba, sin tener en cuenta la penúltima, es decir, *último* rima con *uno*). Si es **sobresdrújula** (acento en la preantepenúltima), vale por dos sílabas menos (o tres, si llegas a tener cuatro sílabas átonas después).</sup>

<sup>3. Una **sinafía** es básicamente una *sinalefa* que ocurre entre dos versos.  La sílaba que originalmente figuraba al principio del segundo verso, al combinar con el verso anterior, ya no cuenta como sílaba, y cualquier consonante final de dicha sílaba, por **enlace** o **encadenamiento**, probablemente se pronunciará al inicio del segundo verso.</sup>

Comment: ¿Podrías incluir enlaces a una definición, explicación, o ejemplo (algo sencillo, por favor) de los términos técnicos que usaste, como por ejemplo *sinalefa*?  También me gustaría entender por qué pusiste **17+1** etc.

Comment: Si no te gustan los guiones que agregué, haz un rollback.  Los puse porque parecía que estaba hablando de la manteca.

Comment: @aparente001 añadí información sobre el tema

Comment: Wow, gracias.  Dos preguntas más: ¿Cómo acordarse de lo que quieren decir *sinalefa, sinéresis*, y *sinafía*?  ¿A qué se refería Manjusri con *elisión*?  Conozco la *liaison* en francés.  ¿Se relaciona con eso?